# Using content property to get favicon?

Tags: css, wordpress, favicon

I'm editing the CSS of a WordPress theme in order to make it fit my needs better. I've come across what, as far as I can tell, retrieves the favicon for different social media sites.

```
.social-menu li a[href*="flickr.com"]::before { content: '\f16e'; }
```

I follow that it looks for flickr.com in the url I provide, but what's the content property doing? How could I change the content field to support another site, such as StackOverflow?

Comment: You'll need to research "icon fonts" and "pseudo-elements" as well as "attribute selectors". Off To the Search Box!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Paulie_D said, icon fonts.

The `content` property is pointing to a Unicode character in a icon font set. The CSS selector is prependnig the icon (via pseudo element) to an anchor element `<a>` that has a link that contains `flickr.com`.

This might be a coincidence but the current version of FontAwesome uses the same unicode character `\f16e` for Flickr.

As far as *"supporting other sites, such as StackOverflow,"* you'll be at the mercy of the icon font. What ever the icon font provides is what you can use.

If the site is indeed using FontAweseom then you'll have quite a few icon options available to you, including StackOverflow `\f16c`. Here is a list of all the [FontAwesome Icons](http://fontawesome.io/icons/).

Comment: It is indeed using FontAwesome to select icons, thank you for the help!